# Conjecture on an asymptotic expansion $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\mu x}}{x} (e^{\pm ix^n}-1) dx$ from Mathematica

Tags: integration, asymptotics

For $n\in \mathbb N$, I conjecture the asymptotic expansion
$$I_n(\mu) := \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\mu x}}{x} (e^{\pm ix^n}-1) dx = \log\mu + \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \gamma \pm \frac{i\pi}{2n} \right) + O(\mu),$$
as $\mu \to 0^+$. Here, $\gamma$ is the Euler gamma constant. Is this true?

For $n=2,3,4$, the conjecture is verified by Mathematica. Explicit closed form for $I_n(\mu)$ can be obtained (in terms of complicated special functions), and taking the series expansion gives the above result.

Also, for $n=2$, I previously asked a question [Asymptotic evaluation of $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{x} (e^{i\alpha \lambda x^2}-1) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619360/asymptotic-evaluation-of-int-0-infty-frace-lambda-xx-ei-alpha-la) , where the answer involves explicit computation of $I_2(\mu)$. Hence, this question is a generalization to the previous question.

I appreciate if one only finds the leading behavior $I_n(\mu) = \log \mu + O(1)$.

Comment: This may or may not help: Since $\log \mu  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - x}  - {\rm e}^{ - \mu x} }}{x}{\rm d}x} $, $$
I_n (\mu ) = \log \mu  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - \mu x \pm {\rm i}x^n }  - {\rm e}^{ - x} }}{x}{\rm d}x} .
$$

Comment: @Gary I think your one-line expression helps, since the last integral does not diverge as $\mu \to 0$. Hence, I think the above expression is an almost-proof that $I_n(\mu) = \log \mu + O(1)$! Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that
$$
\frac{dI_n}{d\mu} = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu x}(1-e^{\pm i x^n}) dx = \frac{1}{\mu} - \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu x + ix^n} dx.
$$
The latter term is (after a substitution) a stationary phase type integral one could show is $O(\mu)$, so you have the leading order behaviour.  The fact that this latter integral is $O(\mu)$ is also essentially what you'd need to show that @Gary's remainder term is constant + $O(\mu)$.  I guess what remains is to show that constant is what you think it is.

Comment: Is it obvious that we can differentiate under the integral sign?

Comment: Obviousness is in the eye of the beholder.  The integrand is continuously differentiable (and decays exponentially so no problems at infinity).

Comment: Considering $dI_n/d\mu$ is a cool idea! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

I looked at
$$I_n(\mu) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\mu x}}{x} (e^{ ix^n}-1)\, dx$$

Using $x^n=t$ leads to
$$I_n= \frac 1n \int_0^\infty \frac{ e^{-\mu \,   t^{\frac{1}{n}}}}{t}\left(e^{i t}-1\right)\,dt$$ Mathematica provides solutions in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions.

Defining
$$J_n=\frac 1 \mu \Big[I_n -\log(\mu)-\frac{  n-1}{n}\gamma-\frac{i \pi }{2 n}  \Big]$$ (this is obviously the correct conjecture) and
$$\color{blue}{\large J_n=-\frac{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}\exp\left(i \frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)}$$

Comment: I suggest to put a $\Gamma(1/n)$ on factor of $K_n$

Comment: @LL3.14. I was just retyping since I found the result. In any manner, many thanks for the suggestion. Cheers :-)

Comment: Great ! Much better!

Comment: So you obtained the $O(\mu)$ term, which is one order higher than I expected! Thanks for your answer as always!